# spark executor lost failure

Tags: scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, executor

I am using the databricks spark cluster (AWS), and testing on my scala experiment.
I have some issue when training on a 10 GB data with LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS algorithm.
The code block where I met the issue is as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
val algorithm = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
algorithm.run(training_set)
```

First I got a lot executor lost failure and java out of memory issues, then I repartitioned my training_set with more partitions and the out of memory issues are gone, but Still get executor lost failure.

My cluster has 72 cores and 500GB ram in total.
Can any one give some idea on this?

Comment: Have u found any solution? I'm also facing the same issue..

Comment: Yes, my issue is that my feature vector is very large and sparse, while I am using the dense vector. If I choose to use the sparse vector format, then I face no issues, and spark trains the model in a really fast speed.

Comment: Hi, How do you convert it into sparse vector format?

Comment: Hi, you can check here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html, it has both scala and python code

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I didn't realize that it was a memory / features problem.  Decreasing # of features has solved the cryptic exception in my case.

Answer (score 5):

LBFGS uses dense vector for storing betas (feature weights) internally and everything is in memory. So regardless of sparsity of features in training set, the total count of features is something to be mindful about.

So to solve this user should either increase executor memory or limit total count of features in the training set.

Comment: Decided to post an answer, although it seems that original SO managed to bypath his issue already, cause this one was a big issue for us, without actionable symptoms.